# Cannot get my jquery ajax call to return xml

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a call:

```
$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/maze/View/${maze}", 
                                    function(response){drawMaze(response);});
```

in a jsp. it calls:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Got here");
        URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        String [] path = url.getPath().split("/");

        mazeJPA.Maze maze = mazes.getMaze(Integer.parseInt(
                                                    path[path.length - 1]));
        System.out.println(maze.getId());
        response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(xmlString(maze));       
        out.flush();

    }
```

and the printlns print what I expect to the console in Eclipse. I have a javascript function

```
function drawMaze(response)
```

defined in a seperate script file but I cannot get the xml to process in it. The error in the javascript console is:

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
get stack: function () { [native code] }
message: "response is not defined"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
__proto__: Error
```

What am I not understanding here?

[edit]
This is the js in my jsp:

```
$.get("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/maze/View/${maze}", 
                                    function(response){drawMaze(response);});
```

and currently I only have the function defined. I was attempting to write the xml but that wasn't working either. The function isn't getting called I think but I can't figure out why.

Comment: `response is not defined` is a pretty big clue. Your issue is likely that the call is failing, or that you haven't pushed the response into `response`. Are you sure it doesn't expect JSON? Please provide more JS code.

Comment: If you use fiddler to examine whats actually coming back in the response, does it look like the XML you're expecting? (I suspect a large part of the problem is $.get() isn't actually passing a response XML blob into your handler.)

Comment: A good place to start would be to fire up Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug and inspect the XML which is returned from the server to see if it's what you expect.

Comment: My xmlString method is producing the xml I expect. It isn't getting into the function. I can't find it in developer tools to inspect only the error.

Comment: I have no code in the function yet. My intention is to draw on a canvas based on the xml. I had a call with no parameter and drew from this function and that worked but when I add the parameter and the $get(..) the xml is not returned. It is produced in my servlet thats all I can confirm at the moment.

Comment: Ahh looking in the network tab of the console I can see the xml and the responseRequest URL:http://localhost:8080/mazeWeb/maze/View/1003
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK                                                       The preview contains my xml

Comment: There is also a Response tab with my xml in it.

Comment: something went wrong parsererror Error {} so I think I have xml errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it working now thanks for the pointers I wouldn't really have known where to start without this thread. I wasn't expecting to have to work with Ajax on this project and, as usual, I am in a hurry. My call now looks like this:

```
<script>
$.ajax( '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/maze/View/${maze}', {
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'xml',
      success: function( response ) {
        drawMaze( response);
      },
      error: function( req, status, err ) {
        console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
      }
    });
</script>
```

I am not sure if the get call I was using was incorrect but after many alterations this is the one I ended up using. I also had some xml parse errors (with my xml) which I had to fix but now with my drawMaze method looking like:

```
function drawMaze(response)
{
    algoName = $(response).find("algorithm");
    console.log(algoName.text());
}
```

I have the correct text in the console. I can get on with the processing I need to do now.